# My Android Game is Crashing (Unfortunately stopped)

Tags: android, eclipse, exception, native

I am having a problem about my game. It stopped once I clicked the New Game button(btnnewgame2). Once I clicked it, it should to go my main game which is LunetaPark1. I'm sorry if my code is too long (it is the whole code actually). Kindly take a look at it. I dunno what's the problem. Once I found out the answer for this, my other activity will be running smoothly.Please do help me.

**NewGame1**

```
public class NewGame1 extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_game1);

}

public void action(View v){
int id = v.getId();
if (id==R.id.btnnewgame2){
Intent intent= new Intent(this,LunetaPark1.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
if (id==R.id.btnhighscore1){
    Intent intent= new Intent(this,HighScore.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
if (id==R.id.btnexit3){
    Intent intent= new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
if (id==R.id.btnback7){
    Intent intent= new Intent(this,LvlForm1.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

}

}
```

**LunetaPark1**

```
public class LunetaPark1 extends Activity {
static MediaPlayer mp1;
MediaPlayer jump;
MediaPlayer takecoin;
GameLoopThread3 gameLoopThread;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // for no title
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(new GameView(this));
    }

    public class GameView extends SurfaceView {
    Bitmap bmp;
    Bitmap background, taya, note1;
    Bitmap run1;
    Bitmap run6;
    Bitmap jump2;
    Bitmap coin;
    Bitmap exit;

    // MediaPlayer mp1,jump,takecoin;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    // private gameloop gameLoopThread;
    private int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, delay = 0, getx, gety, sound = 1;
    int show = 0, sx, sy = 0;
    int cspeed = 0, kspeed = 0, gameover = 0;
    int score = 0, health = 120, reset = 0;
    private int min = 1, sec = 0;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable mRunnable;
    private boolean isStop = false;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")


    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(sec <= 0){
                    if(min > 0){
                        sec = 59;
                        min--;
                        isStop = false;
                    }
                    else{
                        //stop timer here
                        Log.e("TIMER", "timer stop!");
                        mHandler.removeCallbacks(this);
                        isStop = true;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    sec--;
                    isStop = false;
                }

                Log.i("TIMER", "min: " + min + " sec: " + sec);
                if(!isStop){
                    mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);

                }
            }
        }, 1000);


        gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread3(this);
        holder = getHolder();

        holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                // for stoping the game
                gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);
                gameLoopThread.getThreadGroup().interrupt();
            }

            @SuppressLint("WrongCall")
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
                gameLoopThread.start();

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                    int width, int height) {
            }
        });

        // getting the screen size
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

        sx = display.getWidth();
        sy = display.getHeight();
        ;
        cspeed = x / 4;
        kspeed = x / 4;
        background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.imgluneta);
        run1 = BitmapFactory
                .decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.run1);
        run6 = BitmapFactory
                .decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.run6);
        jump2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.run11);
        coin = BitmapFactory
                .decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.coin);
        exit = BitmapFactory
                .decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.exit);
        taya = BitmapFactory
                .decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.taya);
        note1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.note1);

        exit = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(exit, 25, 25, true);

        background = Bitmap
                .createScaledBitmap(background, 2 * sx, sy, true);
        // health dec
        note1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(note1, sx, sy, true);

        mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(LunetaPark1.this, R.raw.game);
        jump = MediaPlayer.create(LunetaPark1.this, R.raw.jump);
        takecoin = MediaPlayer.create(LunetaPark1.this, R.raw.cointake);
    }

    // on touch method

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            show = 1;

            getx = (int) event.getX();
            gety = (int) event.getY();
            // exit
            if (getx < 25 && gety < 25) {
                System.exit(0);

            }
            // sound off
            if (getx > 25 && getx < 60) {
                if (gety < 25) {
                    sound = 0;
                    mp1.stop();
                }
            }
            // sound on
            if (getx > 61 && getx < 90) {
                if (gety < 25) {
                    sound = 1;

                }
            }
            // restart game
            if (getx > 91 && gety < 25) {
                if (health <= 0) {
                    gameLoopThread.setPause(0);
                    health = 100;
                    score = 0;

                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @SuppressLint("WrongCall")
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

        // background moving
        z = z - 10;
        if (z == -sx) {
            z = 0;
            canvas.drawBitmap(background, z, 0, null);

        } else {
            canvas.drawBitmap(background, z, 0, null);
        }

        // running player

        x += 5;
        if (x == 20) {
            x = 5;
        }

        if (show == 0) {
            if (x % 2 == 0) {
                int height = run1.getHeight();
                canvas.drawBitmap(run1, sx / 16, (15 * sy / 18) - height / 2, null);
                // kinfe hit
                if (kspeed == 20) {
                    kspeed = sx;
                    health -= 25;
                    canvas.drawBitmap(note1, 0, 0, null);

                }
            } else {
                int height = run6.getHeight();
                canvas.drawBitmap(run6, sx / 16, (15 * sy / 18) - height / 2, null);
                // kinfe hit
                if (kspeed == 20) {
                    kspeed = sx / 2;
                    health -= 25;
                    canvas.drawBitmap(note1, 0, 0, null);
                }
            }
        }

        // for jump
        if (show == 1) {
            if (sound == 1) {
                jump.start();
            }
            int height=jump2.getHeight();
            canvas.drawBitmap(jump2, sx / 16, (3 * sy / 4)-height, null);
            // score
            if (cspeed <= (sx / 8)-height/2 && cspeed >= (sx / 16)-height/2) {
                if (sound == 1) {
                    takecoin.start();

                }
                cspeed = sx / 2;
                score += 10;
            }

            // jump-hold
            delay += 1;
            if (delay == 3) {
                show = 0;
                delay = 0;
            }
        }

        // for coins
        cspeed = cspeed - 5;
        if (cspeed == -sx / 2) {
            cspeed = sx / 2;
            canvas.drawBitmap(coin, cspeed, 3 * sy / 4, null);
        } else {
            canvas.drawBitmap(coin, cspeed, 3 * sy / 4, null);
        }

        // kinfe
        kspeed = kspeed - 20;
        int height = taya.getHeight();
        canvas.drawBitmap(taya, kspeed, (15 * sy / 18) - height / 2, null);
        if (kspeed < 0) {
            kspeed = sx;
            health -= 25;

    } 

        // score
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        paint.setTextSize(15);
        paint.setTextAlign(Align.LEFT);
        canvas.drawText("Score :" + score, 3 * sx / 4, 20, paint);
        // exit
        canvas.drawBitmap(exit, 0, 0, null);
        if (sound == 1) {
            mp1.start();
            mp1.setLooping(true);
        }

        // health
        Paint myPaint = new Paint();
        myPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        myPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        canvas.drawText("Health :" + health, 0, (sy / 8) - 5, myPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(0, sy / 8, health, sy / 8 + 10, myPaint);

        // game over
        if (health <= 0) {
            gameover = 1;
            mp1.stop();
            canvas.drawText("GAMEOVER OVER", sx / 2, sy / 2, myPaint);
            canvas.drawText("YOUR SCORE : " + score, sx / 2, sy / 4,
                    myPaint);
            canvas.drawText("Restart", 91, 25, myPaint);
            gameLoopThread.setPause(1);
        }
        // restart

        if (reset == 1) {
            gameLoopThread.setPause(0);
            health = 100;
            score = 0;
        }

        // timer
        Paint mypaint = new Paint();
        myPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        myPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        mypaint.setTextSize(50);
        canvas.drawText("Timer :" + min + sec,min, sec, mypaint);
    }


}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    LunetaPark1.mp1.isPlaying();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    LunetaPark1.mp1.pause();
}   


}
```

**GameLoopThread3**

```
public class GameLoopThread3 extends Thread 
{

   private GameView view;
   static final long FPS = 10;
   private boolean running = false;
   boolean isPaused;

   public GameLoopThread3(GameView view) 
   {
         this.view = view;
   }

   public void setRunning(boolean run) 
   {
         running = run;
   }

   public void setPause(int i)
   {
       synchronized (view.getHolder()) 
       {
            if(i==0)
            {
                isPaused=false;
            }
            if(i==1)
            {
                isPaused = true;
            }
        }
   }


@SuppressLint("WrongCall")
@Override

  public void run() 
  {
       long ticksPS = 100;
       long startTime = 0;
       long sleepTime;
          while (running) 
          {
              //pause and resume

            if (isPaused) 
            {
                  try 
                  {
                      this.sleep(50);
                  } 
                  catch (InterruptedException e) 
                  {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                  }
            }
            else
            {
                 Canvas c = null;
                 startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                 try 
                {
                        c = view.getHolder().lockCanvas();
                        synchronized (view.getHolder()) 
                        {
                            view.onDraw(c);
                        }
                } 
                 finally 
                 {
                     if (c != null) 
                        {
                            view.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                        }
                 }
            }
                 sleepTime = ticksPS-(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime); 

                 try 
                 {

                        if (sleepTime > 0)
                           sleep(sleepTime);
                        else
                           sleep(10);
                 } 
            catch (Exception e) {}
          }
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
01-24 20:20:14.408: E/AndroidRuntime(1242): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-24 20:20:14.408: E/AndroidRuntime(1242): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
01-24 20:20:14.408: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
01-24 20:20:14.408: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
01-24 20:20:14.408: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
01-24 20:20:14.408: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-24 20:20:14.408: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-24 20:20:14.408: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-24 20:20:14.408: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-24 20:20:14.408: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-24 20:20:14.408: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-24 20:20:14.408: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-24 20:20:14.408: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-24 20:20:14.408: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-24 20:20:14.408: E/AndroidRuntime(1242): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-24 20:20:14.408: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-24 20:20:14.408: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-24 20:20:14.408: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
01-24 20:20:14.408: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     ... 11 more
01-24 20:20:14.408: E/AndroidRuntime(1242): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.luksongbakagame/com.example.luksongbakagame.LunetaPark1}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
01-24 20:20:14.408: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1618)
01-24 20:20:14.408: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
01-24 20:20:14.408: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
01-24 20:20:14.408: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
01-24 20:20:14.408: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
01-24 20:20:14.408: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
01-24 20:20:14.408: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     at com.example.luksongbakagame.NewGame1.action(NewGame1.java:30)
01-24 20:20:14.408: E/AndroidRuntime(1242):     ... 14 more
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.luksongbakagame"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.luksongbakagame.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.luksongbakagame.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.luksongbakagame.StartForm"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_start_form" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.luksongbakagame.OptionForm"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_option_form" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.luksongbakagame.HelpForm"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_help_form" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.luksongbakagame.About"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_about" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.luksongbakagame.PracticeMode"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_practice_mode" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.luksongbakagame.NormalMode"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_normal_mode" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.luksongbakagame.ChallengeMode"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_challenge_mode" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.luksongbakagame.LvlForm1"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_lvl_form1" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.luksongbakagame.LvlForm2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_lvl_form2" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.luksongbakagame.NewGame1"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_new_game1" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.luksongbakagame.NewGame2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_new_game2" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.luksongbakagame.NewGame3"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_new_game3" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.luksongbakagame.NewGame4"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_new_game4" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.luksongbakagame.NewGame5"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_new_game5" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.luksongbakagame.NewGame6"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_new_game6" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.luksongbakagame.NewGame7"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_new_game7" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.luksongbakagame.NewGame8"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_new_game8" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.luksongbakagame.NewGame9"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_new_game9" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.luksongbakagame.NewGame10"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_new_game10" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.luksongbakagame.NewGame"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_new_game"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.luksongbakagame.NewGame11"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_new_game11" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.luksongbakagame.NewGame12"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_new_game12" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.luksongbakagame.NewGame13"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_new_game13" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.luksongbakagame.NewGame14"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_new_game14" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.luksongbakagame.HighScore"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_high_score" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: make sure that you have declared `LunetaPark1` class in ur `manifest.xml`...

Comment: Check your manifest...looks like you haven't declared the activity in manifest.

Comment: How to declare it in manifest when I'm using Java based in my LunetaPark1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

launcher activity declare like this in ur manifest.xml. (launcher acticity is a starting activity of application)

```
       <activity
            android:name="packagename.LauncherActivityName"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

other classes declare like this

```
   <activity
        android:name="packagename.OtherActivityName"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```

string declaration

```
<string name="urstringname">Your String</string>
```

eg.

```
<string name="myname">Ann Lee</string>
```

here u can access the string "Ann Lee" by the string name myname.

Comment: I have that xml on my splashscreen but I dunno how to put Luneta Park.

Comment: u should  add new <activity> below ur launcher activity or post ur manifest.xml...

Comment: I really can't understand. How can I declare LunetaPark1.java? Should I put it inside NewGame1.java manifest or add another?

Comment: add this before </application> in ur manifest `<activity
        android:name="com.example.luksongbakagame.LunetaPark1"
        android:label="change this too" >
    </activity>`

Comment: How can I add "android:label="@string/(XML)" if my LunetaPark1 class don't have an xml? As I understand, that string is an xml? Am I right?

Comment: `@string/stringname` will in `strings.xml` u ll get this in `res/values/strings.xml` declare string there and access anywhre u want..with the name.. check my editted ans i ll add example to declare string..

Comment: I don't have lunetapark1 in my strings.xml coz I used java-based codings in that class.

Comment: what label? I'm sorry if i have so many questions, It's just that I want to learn and understand. I hope you don't mind :)

Comment: its ok buddy...check this   http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html

Comment: Is this right?

    ` <activity
            android:name="com.example.luksongbakagame.LunetaPark1"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_luneta_park1"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>`

I add an xml file in layout.

Comment: I've accepted it. Sorry. I can't vote this answer right now. I have only 8 reputations. Hahaha. Thanks again.

Comment: hehehe... if i can i ll defnetly help u... :)